# How to set CSS to move the block when sliding down the webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am a beginner in programming, I have a problem and want to ask you!
At present, there is a layout that the green area appears on the left side, such as area A in the picture, but when the mouse slides down, the green area is about to become area B in the picture.
But I don’t know how to make such a change, no Know if someone can give me a little help? thanks

```css
* {
  border: 1px solid #222;
}

html {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.content {
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  max-width: 600px;
}
.content .main {
  flex: 2;
  background-color: #f80d77;
  padding: 20px;
  line-height: 1.6;
}
.content .main .title {
  font-size: 60px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #71ff05;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
}
.content .side {
  flex: 1;
}
.content .side .side_wrap {
  background-color: #ff5b0f;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="warp">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="main">
      <div class="title">TITLE</div>
      Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia libero explicabo est hic illo! Beatae, optio molestiae, debitis itaque in ullam odio corporis neque delectus facilis nobis omnis. Cum voluptatem vel, accusantium repellendus consectetur facilis dolore possimus deleniti corporis placeat iure exercitationem fugiat repellat ipsa eaque? Quam alias, sit corporis earum doloremque eos et voluptatem tempora, similique mollitia pariatur suscipit porro reprehenderit ea ut in quidem! Deleniti soluta nostrum at quidem itaque, maxime enim sint sequi recusandae possimus dicta natus quo harum! Veniam ut dolorem, laboriosam mollitia ab quasi non ratione officia iure, nam, molestiae sunt pariatur explicabo cupiditate deserunt?
      Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia libero explicabo est hic illo! Beatae, optio molestiae, debitis itaque in ullam odio corporis neque delectus facilis nobis omnis. Cum voluptatem vel, accusantium repellendus consectetur facilis dolore possimus deleniti corporis placeat iure exercitationem fugiat repellat ipsa eaque? Quam alias, sit corporis earum doloremque eos et voluptatem tempora, similique mollitia pariatur suscipit porro reprehenderit ea ut in quidem! Deleniti soluta nostrum at quidem itaque, maxime enim sint sequi recusandae possimus dicta natus quo harum! Veniam ut dolorem, laboriosam mollitia ab quasi non ratione officia iure, nam, molestiae sunt pariatur explicabo cupiditate deserunt?
      Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia libero explicabo est hic illo! Beatae, optio molestiae, debitis itaque in ullam odio corporis neque delectus facilis nobis omnis. Cum voluptatem vel, accusantium repellendus consectetur facilis dolore possimus deleniti corporis placeat iure exercitationem fugiat repellat ipsa eaque? Quam alias, sit corporis earum doloremque eos et voluptatem tempora, similique mollitia pariatur suscipit porro reprehenderit ea ut in quidem! Deleniti soluta nostrum at quidem itaque, maxime enim sint sequi recusandae possimus dicta natus quo harum! Veniam ut dolorem, laboriosam mollitia ab quasi non ratione officia iure, nam, molestiae sunt pariatur explicabo cupiditate deserunt?
    </div>
    <div class="side">
       <ul class="side_wrap">
         <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</li>
         <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</li>
         <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</li>
         <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</li>
         <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</li>
         <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</li>
       </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `position:sticky;` with element.

You could use [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_sticky_element.asp) as reference.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know about this attribute~
I’m sorry that I didn’t fully express my question. The problem I encountered today is that he is not only fixed at the top of the page, he also needs to slide from the original left block. When the mouse scrolls up and touches the top of the webpage, it needs to extend the entire green block to the left and right sides of the webpage. This is something I don't know how to achieve?